# ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0 tips

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to group all values of my Column `DATUM` of the Table `test_tbl` which are greater than **01.01.2020** . When I run the query:

```
SELECT to_date("DATUM", 'YYYYMM')
FROM test_tbl
WHERE to_date("DATUM", 'YYYYMM') >= to_date('2020-01-01' ,'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY to_date("DATUM", 'YYYYMM')
```

I get the following Error

> ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0.

The table `test_tbl` looks like:

| DATUM (varchar2) |
| --- |
| 201701 |
| 202001 |
| 201901 |
| 201801 |
| 202003 |

When I run only the GROUP BY without the WHERE CLAUSE the date convertation works and there are no NULL values or somithing similiar

```
SELECT to_date("DATUM", 'YYYYMM')
FROM test_tbl
GROUP BY to_date("DATUM", 'YYYYMM')
```

`

Comment: What is the data type of DATUM?  If it is not a VARCHAR2, then you should not be using TO_DATE, which takes a varchar2 as its first input parameter.

Comment: its VARCHAR2, also when I convert the column  to DATE datatype I get the error

Comment: What is the data type of column `DATUM`? If it is a `VARCHAR2` or number then: Why on earth do you store data values as string, use proper `DATE` format. If it is a `DATE` then: Never call `TO_DATE` on a value which is already a `DATE`. Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Are there really only 5 rows of test data?  I ask because I was able to create your table, add the 5 rows, and run your query without issue.  Results were 2020-01-01 and 2020-03-01. Also, what is the purpose of GROUP BY here?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit also when I convert the column to DATE datatype I get the error

Comment: @Stilgar no there are over 300k rows but as I mentioned I can group them all but can not filter with WHERE Clause at the same time

Comment: GROUP BY would not attempt to convert your values to DATE so it would work regardless of the content.  You might try a REGEX in a query to remove all numeric values and see if you have any odd values in there.

Comment: How do you convert the column to `DATE`?

Answer (score 2):

This is a data error. Somewhere in your DATUM column you have a string which cannot be cast to a date. This is always a risk when we store data as the wrong datatype.

If you are on Oracle 12c R2 or higher you can easily locate the errant row(s) with a query like this:

```
select * from your_table
where validate_conversion(datum as date, 'yyyymm') = 0
```

If you are on an earlier version of the database you can create a function which does something similar....

```
create or replace function is_date(p_str  in varchar2
                                  ,p_mask in varchar2 := 'yyyymm' ) return number is
  n pls_integer;
begin
  declare
    dt date;
  begin
    dt := to_date(p_str, p_mask);
    n := 1;
  exception
    when others then
      n := 0;
  end;
  return n;
end;
/
```

Like `validate_conversion()` this returns 1 for valid dates and 0 for invalid ones.

```
select * from your_table
where is_date(datum, 'yyyymm') = 0
```

This approach is safer because it applies Oracle's actual date verification mechanism. Whereas, using pattern matching regexes etc leaves us open to weak patterns which pass strings which can't be cast to dates.

Comment: ++ I agree that VALIDATE_CONVERSION is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Validate_Conversion is working, but I only get an empty result. So this means it returns only "1" for valid dates. What else can I do?

Comment: Also the second solution results in an empty result

Answer (score 0):

Your datum column would need to contain only numeric data in order to be processed as a date in the format you specified.  Plus the last two digits would need to be between 01 and 12; but that's a separate issue since your error message is complaining about the value for year.

So you could check for invalid values with:

```
    SELECT
     datum
    ,LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(datum,'[0-9]','')) as char_count
FROM test_tbl
WHERE LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(datum,'[0-9]','')) > 0
;
```

Should spin through 300k rows fairly quickly.

Comment: Using `WHERE LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(datum,'[0-9]','')) > 0` would be one of the slowest possible solution.